# AT+CUSD Follow code not working ( USSD Session )

Tags: gsm, at-command, modem, gsmcomm

i am having an issue with m35 gsm modem

i tired both GSM mode and UCS2 Mode , and tried diffrent settings

here is the issue , when i send a normal AT+CUSD that doesn't need actions ,

such as

```
AT+CUSD=1,"*222#",15
```

i get a respond

```
+CUSD: 2,"PixX 4G, Balance 79,94DA, International Credit  200,00DA",15
OK
```

and i can use the gsm modem without any issues , but when i send one that need action such as

```
AT+CUSD=1,"*610#",15
```

i get this

```
+CUSD: 1,"1: Subscription
                         2: Info",68

OK
```

the issue here is that i can't send back anything

```
AT+CUSD=1,"*610#",15
+CUSD: 1,"1: Subscription
          2: Info",68
OK

AT+CUSD=1,"2",15
ERROR
```

i tried with UCS2 i tried changing that 15 at the end , the exact same code works on various other modems , to choose from the menu all i have to do is send the respond , the same way i send the AT code so i send AT+CUSD=1,"1",15 or AT+CUSD=1,"2",15 and it's works , but on this modem it's didn't work ,
i tried reading the officiel docs for it and it's doesn't state any diffrent way , is there others ways ?

btw i can't use *610*1# because it's not supported by my sim card provider